# Displaying extra field - specification in store front end

Tags: opencart

I have added an extra field `Specification` in `Catalog->Product->Data` tab.
This text is stored in a column called `specification` in `product_description` table.

Now I want to display this information in my Store Front (default theme). On product page there is a tab `Specification` that displays attribute. I want to display `specification` instead of attribute.

Please suggest me how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: edit Your `Product` model - should be in `catalog/model/product/product.php` - find the method `getProduct` and edit the SQL that selects the product details to also get the `specification` column.

Second: edit Your `Product` controller - should be in `catalog/controller/product/product.php` and make sure that Your `specification` column will be added to `$this->data['specification']`, e.g.

Third: edit Your `Product` detail template - should be in `catalog/view/theme/default/templates/product/product.tpl` and find that part where `<div class="tabs">` (or similar) is - then find the tab for specification and print out Your `specification` column here...

Should be done.